# CSS class height and width for input tag are interpreted differently by chrome

Tags: html, css, margin

I developed and test a portion of HTML div and when I put that portion in another HTML page.  The input tag css are rendered differently.  So I got into the debug mode. The CSS box model show the margin, border and padding are the same but the dimension is 16x16 instead of 12x10?  I want it to render as 12x10? What causing this?

```
.pbg{
  text-align:center; 
  width:16px; 
  height:16px;
  float:left; 
  margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

Comment: the above snippet is what's in chrome's debugger? because if not, then why do you have `16` for both instead of `12` and `10`?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The pbg class is in the chrome debugger.  The CSS box model shows 16x16 instead of 12x10 and I don't know why

Comment: chrome's debugger should show you all of the rules being applied to an element, and which ones were overriden. you may have 12x10 set somewhere, but another rule that is more specific overwrites and changes them to 16.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have a CSS rule somewhere else that is set to 12x10. In your inspector you should be able to see the file and line that has declared 12x10 instead of 16x16. Then just navigate to that file and that line number and make the appropriate changes.

Or if you want to force all .pbg elements to stay at 16x16 all the time go with adding the following to your CSS file:

```
.pbg{
  text-align:center; 
  width:16px !important; 
  height:16px !important;
  float:left; 
  margin-bottom:1px;
}
```